# How do I print a key without value from a dictionary that has multiple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm sure there is a simple answer just have not been able to find it directly.

If I have a dictionary stored in a variable, I would like to pull out a single key and print it to the console without the attached value. Also it would be helpful to see how to get the value without the key, and both the key and value together.

So,

```
pocket = {"change":14,"lint":"handfull"}
```

How would I proceed to print just change; print just the value in change; and print change and its value together but without the brackets, comma and quotations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have all the keys:

```
print(dictionary.keys())
```

All the values:

```
print(dictionary.values())
```

All items:

```
print(dictionary.items())
```

To print them one by one, loop through it:

```
for key in dictionary.keys():
    print("Key: ", key)
for value in dictionary.values():
    print("Value: ", value)
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    print("Key: ", k)
    print("Value: ", v)
```

To understand dictionaries better, click [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)!

Well, hope this helps!

Comment: You need to answer the part to "pull out a single key and print it", which is `print dictionary['change']`

Comment: That part isn't so clear, pulling a key means you know the key name, or pull it by the value, which may vary..

Answer (score 1):

To just print a single *specific* value from a dictionary, change in your example, you have to **know** the key.

To just print the "first" value in a dictionary is possible **but** you shouldn't ever use it as it is unpredictable.

To print the value only:

```
pocket.get("change", "penniless") # if the key is missing gives the default
```

or

```
pocket["change"]  # can fail
```

Since you must always know the key to talk reliably about a single entry you can always print the key or the pair.